# Generate Simple HTML pages?

Tags: forms, dynamic

Okay I have an idea in my head, but I am not sure if you can even do it or not. I want to have where I can fill out a form with some information and when I click submit it will create a new  page from a template that fills in some blanks with the information from the form. So every page will look the same except a few pictures and the name on the page. 
I am wondering what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Not from direct HTML or client-side stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a... complex question.

It depends on how much experience you have, and what resources you have available. The easiest way would be to use a PHP script or similar that fills in the spaces in the template with the submitted form data. For that you need access to a web server.

If you don't have access to a web server, you could generate a page using javascript client side, I suggest using a library like jQuery.

---

### Links

- [PHP Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/)
- [Javascript Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/)
- [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/)

Those should get you what you need to know.

Comment: When you ask if I have access to the web server, do you mean the actually hosting and everything?

Comment: Not necessarily hosting, but you need a web server to use PHP since it is a server-side scripting language. You can set up a web server on your own computer if you want. I suggest you do some research on Apache.

Comment: Oh, I can use PHP with my site. I have access to that stuff